# IBM System X M4 Series Servers Oracle Linux Support

Tags: linux, oracle, ibm-xseries

Is Oracle Linux runnable/compatible with the M4 Series of the IBM System X Servers?

In their compatibility website, most compatible machines listed are those from Dell and HP..there are IBM system x..but all are of older models..

(This is the link of the tested configurations/compatible machines for Oracle Linux: http://linux.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=102:1:2850003747338068:pg_R_27262430945134281:NO&pg_min_row=1&pg_max_rows=20&pg_rows_fetched=20)

We currently have no machines to test the Oracle Linux if it will work...
If you guys could confirm for me if it will work on IBM System x M4 series that would be great and appreciated :)

This is for one of our clients who would like to run Oracle Linux on one of their machines that they will purchase from us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: It should.

Oracle Linux is a child of RHEL.  If RHEL is supported on this hardware then you should have no problems with OEL using the RHEL derivative kernel.

The Oracle kernel is based on a more modern but should work.

IBM has a vested interest in making servers that work with current Linux distributions.  Oracle Linux is one of the distributions they provide support for.  It is the 3rd distro in the list at http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/x/os/linux/.

Comment: I see thank you for the confirmation. 
It's just that when I saw the link in my question, no M4 series is in the list..so I kinda doubted if it's supported.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As for 2021, Oracle Linux 8 is still supported on IBM System X M4 series with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel (UEK). Where RHEL 8 and other EL clones cannot even boot anymore on M4 series due to the [removal of SAS2 drivers](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3722151) on RHEL 8.

I've been using Oracle Linux 8 on this hardware to continue receiving software updates on the aging machines.